# Обособление частиц «мол» и «дескать»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, частицы

Частицы "мол" и "дескать" выделяются пунктуационно? Они что, какие-то особенные?
Примеры:

> Он, мол, заболел.

> Ты, дескать, сходи в магазин — купи стиральный порошок.

(Заранее прошу прощения, если где-то допустил ошибку — орфографическую или пунктуационную.)

Answer (score 2):

По Розенталю (Справочник по русскому языку / Пунктуация, § 25, п. 5), **мол** и **дескать** обособляются как *вводные слова, указывающие на источник сообщения*:

http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_25.htm

Answer (score 1):

Особенностью частиц "мол" и "дескать", думаю, является способ их образования.
В этимологическом словаре Крылова:
[мол](http://endic.ru/krylov/Mol-2299.html)
Эта частица, указывающая на то, что произносимые слова передают чужую речь, возникла в результате сокращения глагола *молвил*.
[де́скать](http://endic.ru/krylov/Deskat-27.html)
Это вводное слово, указывающее на то, что приведенные слова — это лишь передача чужой речи, образовалось довольно мудреным способом: из частицы *де* (имеющей, кстати, то же значение, что и все слово *дескать*, то есть являющейся синонимом к нему) и глагола *сказать*, выступающего в усеченной форме — "скать".

Он послал длинную телеграмму моему деду, своему братцу: присмотри, **мол**, хорошее именьице поблизости. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

Князь Карл Радзивилл, когда сел в Венеции на корабль, чтоб ехать с нею к султану, так прямо и объявил нам: **дескать**, с нами отправляется к султану дочь покойной русской императрицы. [Эдвард Радзинский. Княжна Тараканова (1999)]

Частица — это служебная часть речи; частицы не изменяются, не имеют самостоятельного лексического значения  и не являются членами предложений (как и вводные конструкции).

Есть вводные слова, есть вводные сочетания, есть вводные предложения — зачем же обременять классификацию еще и вводными частицами? Тем более что по сути они и есть, собственно, слова (вспомните, в начальных классах при чтении на скорость и предлоги, и союзы тоже засчитываются в качестве слов).